# Android - drawing on canvas not working inside Runnable

Tags: android, multithreading, canvas, draw

This is my first time working with android, and I'm having some trouble drawing on a canvas repeatedly inside a thread. It seems that it only gets drawn once, although the thread is running which I made sure using a `toast` that popped up each time the thread executed (I've removed it because it was bothering me) but the thread is running and the code inside gets executed, it just sort of doesn't redraw...

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity implements Runnable{
    ImageView gameView;
    public int screenWidth, screenHeight, objectSize;
    private static int FPS = 30;
    private boolean rightPressed = false, leftPressed = false;
    private Player player;
    private Thread thread;
    private Canvas canvas;
    private Bitmap blankBitmap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        screenWidth = size.x;
        screenHeight = size.y;
        objectSize = screenWidth/8;
        player = new Player(objectSize, screenWidth/2 - objectSize/2, screenHeight - (objectSize+10));

        blankBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(screenWidth,screenHeight,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        canvas = new Canvas(blankBitmap);
        gameView = new ImageView(this);
        gameView.setImageBitmap(blankBitmap);
        draw();

        setContentView(gameView);

        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            leftPressed = true;
            if((int)event.getX()<=screenWidth/2){
                leftPressed = true;
                rightPressed = false;
                Toast.makeText(this, "left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if((int)event.getX()>screenWidth/2){
                rightPressed = true;
                leftPressed = false;
                Toast.makeText(this, "right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            rightPressed = false;
            leftPressed = false;
            Toast.makeText(this, "released", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    public void draw(){
        canvas.drawColor(Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255));
        player.draw(canvas);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!player.shouldDie()) {
            try {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (!rightPressed && !leftPressed) player.setDx(0);
                        if(rightPressed) player.setDx(player.getSpeed());
                        if(leftPressed) player.setDx(-player.getSpeed());
                        player.update();
                        draw();
                    }
                });
                Thread.sleep(1000/FPS);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also checked that the x of the player does actually change, and if I manually set the dx to like 100 it does actually move the first time it is executed, but not later even though the thread is still running

anyway, here's the Player.class

```
public class Player  {

    private int health, size, x, y;
    private double dx, speed;
    private Paint paint;

    public Player(int size, int x, int y){
        health = 3;
        speed = 1;
        dx = 0;
        this.size = size;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;

        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.argb(255,  26, 128, 182));
    }

    public void draw(Canvas canvas){
        canvas.drawRect(x, y, x+size, y+size, paint);
      }

    public void update(){
        x += dx;
    }

    public void hurt(){
        health--;
    }

    public boolean shouldDie(){
        if(health<=0)return true;
        return false;
    }
    public void posToast(Context context){
        Toast.makeText(context, "X: " + x, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public int getHealth() {
        return health;
    }
    public void setHealth(int health) {
        this.health = health;
    }
    public Paint getPaint() {
        return paint;
    }
    public double getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }
    public void setSpeed(double speed) {
        this.speed = speed;
    }
    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }
    public void setSize(int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }
    public double getDx() {
        return dx;
    }
    public void setDx(double dx) {
        this.dx = dx;
    }
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

If anyone sees anything wrong in here I'd appreciate some help as I'm really confused as to why this doesn't work, especially since this is my first time working with android.

Comment: Seems you forgot to call rePaint() method. In android you have something called inValidate() which does redraw your canvas. You can either add in player draw method or activity draw method. That should do the trick.

Comment: yeah, that did the trick! thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems you forgot to call rePaint() method. In Android, you have something called inValidate() which does redraw your canvas. You can either add in player draw method or activity draw method. That should do the trick.